# My PHP script is excecuting both if and else statements

Tags: php, if-statement, forum

I realise this question has been answered before however each are all specific to everyone's code. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me why both if and else statements are executing. The script is part of a login script for a piece of forum software I am developing.
Thanks
Robbie

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
session_start();
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/forum/config.php");

$connect = mysqli_connect($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPASS,$DBNAME);
if ($connect->connect_errno) {
    die('Connection Error: ' . $connect->connect_errno);
}
$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM forum_users");
while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
  if (($row['username'] == $username) AND ($row['password'] == $password)) {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href = "../forum/"';
        echo '</script>';
  } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href = "../forum/login?password=wrong"';
        echo '</script>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you know both `if` and `else` are being executed?

Comment: You're running a loop against all users in forum_users.  Presumably one matches, and the rest do not.

Comment: you should be doing the username and password check in the sql query and limit the query to 1, `LIMIT 1` and remove the loop since you should only ever get 1 or 0 results.

Comment: may be you need to add some where clauses to your select statement based on username and password entered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching all user data from the database (`SELECT * FROM forum_users`). If you have more than one user with different name or password the `else` statement is executed independend of the username and password input because the username and password can only match one entry in the database.

You should remove the `while` loop and replace it by

```
$row = $query->fetch_array();
if ($row) {
    if (($row['username'] == $username) AND ($row['password'] == $password)) {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href = "../forum/"';
        echo '</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href = "../forum/login?password=wrong"';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also do the whole password check in the query with

```
$secureUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$securePassword = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM forum_users WHERE username='" . $secureUsername . "' AND password='" . $securePassword . "'");
```

and than check if the number of rows equals one.

Answer (score 0):

--edit-- covered in Simon's post above re including username and password in the query

...
Then only run it once:

```
$row = $query->fetch_array();
if ($row) {
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href = "../forum/"';
    echo '</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href = "../forum/login?password=wrong"';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

When you put your credentials into the query, you can easily find out if there's a match on username and password by doing a count() of $query, or fetching one row and seeing if it returns correctly (if it doesn't, username or password is wrong).

Comment: Works aswell but Simon got there before you!